# loop through nested dictionary/list in Python and save key-value pairs

Tags: python, dictionary

I'd like to loop through this nested dict/list and return all occurrences of input key-value pairs. The length and the depth of each level may vary.

For example I'd like to have all the `{'dd': 22}`.

Here's my attempt:

```
d = {'a': 'foo',
    'b': [{'cc': 11},
         {'dd': 22}],
    'c': [{'dd': 22},
         {'ff': 33}]}

def navigate_html(d, key='', value='', ll=[]):
    if isinstance(d, list):
        for v in d:
            yield from navigate_html(v, key, value, ll)
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        for k, v in d.items():
            if k == key and v == value:
                ll.append({k: v})
            else:
                yield from navigate_html(v, key, value, ll)
    return ll

for i in navigate_html(d, 'dd', 22):
    print('---', i)
```

desired output
`[{'dd': 22}, {'dd': 22}]`

**EDIT**
better, try to retrieve `'@content': 'cccc'`

```
d1={'doctype': ['html'],
 'html': [{'@lang': 'en-EN',
   '#text': "ttt",
   'head': [{'#text': 'abc',
     'meta': [{'@charset': 'utf-8', '#text': ''},
      {'@name': 'viewport',
       '@content': 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no',
       '#text': ''},
      {'@name': 'description',
       '@content': 'cccc',
       '#text': '',
       'meta': [{'@name': 'keywords',
         '@content': 'cccc',
         '#text': ''}]
      }]
            }]
          }]
   }
```

expected output:
`[{'@content': 'cccc'}, {'@content': 'cccc'}]`

Comment: is it nested arbitrarily deep?

Comment: yes, the length and the depth of each level may vary

Comment: What's wrong with your attempt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
def navigate_html(nested: dict, key, value):
    for k, v in nested.items():
        if k == key and v == value:
            yield {k: v}
        elif isinstance(v, list):
            for d in v:
                if isinstance(d, dict):
                    yield from navigate_html(d, key, value)

>>> list(navigate_html(d, 'dd', 22))
# => [{'dd': 22}, {'dd': 22}]

>>> list(navigate_html(d1, '@content', 'cccc'))
# => [{'@content': 'cccc'}, {'@content': 'cccc'}]
```

Comment: `navigate_html(d, 'dd', 22)` returns only a generator

Comment: oh, whoops, minor fixable thing though

Comment: also, changing a bit the input dictionary I got error with `.items()` because I think we should check first if `v` it's a dictionary or list

Comment: for example `d1={'doctype': ['html'],
 'html': [{'@lang': 'en-EN',
   '#text': "tttt"}]}`   and `list(navigate_html(d1, '@lang', 'en-EN'))`

Comment: Before I give that a shot, could you first add that and any other examples you had in mind? It wasn't part of your original question.